# SQLite database info

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I want to check if db is created from the device monitor, but
 it is not showing my genymotion emulator.I created a database and table and i want to check it without using logs.Android device monitor serves my requirement but it fails to detect my genymotion device.

[image: this is the screenshot]

Comment: Yep. That's a nice screen shot, all right... Lotsa pixels. Just what you want. Now... did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to show off your screen-capping abilities.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are a lot of people here who are willing to help. However, we need more information. What exactly are we supposed to see in your screenshot? What is missing that you think should be there? Please explain your situation as if we don't know anything about it...because we don't. You should also read [these tips about asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Did you select the Emualtor to run the app after the ddms is started? And also you need to re-enable the adb from the same menu.

Comment: I created a database and table and i want to check it without using logs.Android device monitor serves my requirement but it fails to detect my genymotion device.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to attach your device install drivers on your PC, let device be debuggable in the preferences.

The database of your application is placed at `/data/data/your.app.name/databases` directory. It is possible to see this directory from Android Studio. (open file explorer).

But the better solution is to retrieve this file programmatically.

Comment: yeah,but file explorer is empty as android device monitor is not showing my projects as it is not detecting my genymotion emulator